# Estoy usando el código de student management system, al cambiar unos títulos deja de funcionar

Tags: python, django

estoy trabajando sobre el código y al cambiar el título de la página en el template 'hod_template/base_template', de 'student_tempalate/base_template' y de 'staff_template/base_template' los gráficos de las estadísticas dejan de mostrarse, también veo que desaparece el logout. ¿Qué puedo hacer?, ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Buenas Ivan, con la poca información que nos proporcionas es imposible deducir la causa de tu error. Por favor, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) o haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para mejorar tus preguntas y atraer la atención de más gente. Por ejemplo, podrías mostrar la estructura o/y el código de tu proyecto.